# Strange trigonometric transformation

Tags: trigonometry

I have a problem with this equation. I don't know to to transform it to this form on the right.

$$\sin(2\sin^{-1}(x))= 2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Comment: It becomes simpler if you first write $x=\sin y$ and then expand $ \sin (2y) = 2\sin y\cdot  \cos y = 2\sin y \sqrt{1-\sin^2 y}$.

Comment: @EZz, What is $\sin(2\cos^{-1}(x))=?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some hints:**

Using the double angle identity: $\sin(2\arcsin x)=2\sin(\arcsin x)\cos(\arcsin x)$.

Now draw a right triangle with angle $\theta$, where $\theta=\arcsin x$. What are the sine and cosine of this angle?

Comment: so i get that sin$\theta$=x/z, cos$\theta$=y/z. 2cos*sin=xy/z^{2}, $y= sqrt{z^{2}-x^{2}}$. With z=1 i get 2cos*sin=x*$sqrt{1-x^{2}}$ and i get demanded result, but why z=1 ?

Comment: @EZz $\theta=\arcsin x$ implies that the ratio opposite over hypotenuse is $x/1$.